# ElasticSearch - how to get the auto generated id from an insert query

Tags: c#, mysql, database, elasticsearch, nest

On my ElasticSearch database I need to get the autogenerated id from my insert query (I'm using .NET C#). How to do it? I tried debugging the readRecords response but I didn't find such id.

Basically I need the equivalent of the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` command.

```
var readRecords = elasticClient.Search<HistoryRecord>(s => s
                .Index(elasticIndexName)
                .Filter(f =>
                    f.Term(t => t.MacAddr, historyRecord.MacAddr) &&
                    f.Term(t => t.GroupName, historyRecord.GroupName) &&
                    f.Term(t => t.GroupNo, historyRecord.GroupNo) &&
                    f.Term(t => t.InstrType, historyRecord.InstrType) &&
                    f.Term(t => t.InstrumentAddress, historyRecord.InstrumentAddress) &&
                    f.Term(t => t.InstrumentName, historyRecord.InstrumentName) &&
                    f.Term(t => t.UhhVersion, historyRecord.UhhVersion))).Documents
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the id values from the `ISearchResponse` (based on your code example above) by looking at the objects in the `Hits` collection, rather than the `Documents` collection.  Each `Hit` has an `Id` property.

In the original indexing call (assuming you're doing that individually -- not via the `_bulk` endpoint), you can get the id of the newly indexed document off the `IIndexResponse`'s `Id` property.